# Decrypt sqlCipher in Maven project

Tags: java, maven, encryption, sqlcipher

I have an Android project with a database that has been encrypted using SqlCipher (net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteOpenHelper). This all works and I can access the decrypted data through the DB-browser on my desktop.

However, I have a server-side Maven project (could be anything, but this one is a Maven one) which has to process the data further.

My question is: How do I decrypt the data for processing in a Java/Maven project?

To give an example of code, I currently access the database as such:

```
try {
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:C:\\Users\\Username\\Desktop\\"+path);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage());
    }
    return c;
```

And I use a resultset like this:

```
ResultSet myGet(Connection db, String sql){
    try {
        return db.createStatement().executeQuery(sql);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Before encrypting the database, the above would work, but now it obviously does not. I get the following error:

```
org.sqlite.SQLiteException: [SQLITE_NOTADB]  File opened that is not a database file (file is not a database)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JDBC, you will need a driver specifically built with SQLCipher support. The [SQLCipher Enterprise Program](https://www.zetetic.net/sqlcipher/enterprise/) offers such a driver.